# How to get an array from ArrayBuffer?

Tags: javascript, arrays, arraybuffer, typed-arrays

I have an ArrayBuffer which looks like: 
[image]

This buffer is placed under variable named `myBuffer` and what I'm interested in, is to get the `Uint8Array` from this object.

I tried to loop as:

```
myBuffer.forEach(function(element) {
    console.log(element);
});
```

and to directly access to the Array as:

```
console.log(myBuffer['[[Uint8Array]]']);
console.log(myBuffer['Uint8Array']);
```

but seems none of this is the correct approach

Comment: Just `new Uint8Array(myBuffer)`

Comment: The "properties" enclosed in `[[…]]` (and also `__proto__`) are just a rendering of internal values by the devtools inspector. They don't actually exist on the object.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Those pseudo-properties you are seeing are something the developer console is putting there for your benefit. They aren't really there at all, as a property or a symbol (AFAIK), and even if they were it would be non-standard.

You can easily get a `Uint8Array` view of your buffer the standard way like this though:

```
new Uint8Array(myBuffer)
```

Answer (score 13):

You will first need to convert the array buffer into a typed array, then from there you can use the spread operator to create an array

```
const typedArray = new Uint8Array(myBuffer);
const array = [...typedArray];
```

Comment: Better use `Array.from(typedArray)`, it's more clear about the purpose

Comment: Anyone wondering why this is needed one must convert a typed array (i.e. Uint8array) to an Array object.  typed arrays are not Array's in javascript. See: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Typed_arrays