# A vanilla Array of Floats from an ArrayBuffer

Tags: javascript, arraybuffer

There are a number of questions and resources about getting *Typed* arrays from an `ArrayBuffer`. An example:  [How to get an array from ArrayBuffer?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52391921/how-to-get-an-array-from-arraybuffer). I need an actual *array*

I tried `Array.from(myArrayBuffer)` and get this:

```
//  buf is an ArrayBuffer(878468)
Array.from(buf) //  Array(0)  length: 0
```

Comment: Does the checked answer from the link you provided not work for you?

Comment: `UInt8Array` is  a `TypedArray`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems there were no direct conversion from `ArrayBuffer` to a vanilla array. Two steps are needed

- ArrayBuffer -> TypedArray
- Array.from(typedArray)

So:

```
     let ab = new ArrayBuffer(1000)
     let arr = Array.from(new Float32Array(ab))
```